# Add an element to a multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays

Add an element to a multidimensional array
Tell me how to make it so as to get an array of $params2 from the array $params

```
$params = [
    'id' => 234223,
    'price' => [
        "currencyId" => "RUR",
        "value" => 2000,
    ]
];

$params2 = [
    'id' => 234223,
    'price' => [
        "currencyId" => "RUR",
        "value" => 2000,
        "discountBase" => 3000
    ]
];
```

Comment: How about this? `$params2 = $params; $params2['price']['discountBase'] = 3000;`

Comment: @qrsngky - You should post it as an answer

Comment: @M.Eriksson alright

Comment: There should already be tons of duplicate questions for this.

Answer (score 1):

You can assign it to a new variable `$params2` then assign `$params2['price']['discountBase'] = 3000;`

For example:

```php
$params = [
    'id' => 234223,
    'price' => [
        "currencyId" => "RUR",
        "value" => 2000,
    ]
];

$params2 = $params; 
$params2['price']['discountBase'] = 3000;
var_export($params2);
```

Output:

```
array (
  'id' => 234223,
  'price' => 
  array (
    'currencyId' => 'RUR',
    'value' => 2000,
    'discountBase' => 3000,
  ),
)
```